# Angular 6 - Transform array property into a new set of array

Tags: angular

The code below will generate me a set of arrays with `id` and `title`, however, I need an array with **only** the `title`.

```
 this.categoriesService.getCategories().subscribe(categories => {
   this.categories = categories as Category[];
 });
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want array of strings:

```
this.categoriesService.getCategories().subscribe(categories => {
   this.categories = categories.map(category => category.title);
});
// this.categories = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3',...]
```

If you want array of objects without `id`:

```
this.categoriesService.getCategories().subscribe(categories => {
   this.categories = categories.map(category => {
     return {title: category.title};
   });
});
// this.categories = [{title: 'title1'}, {title: 'title2'}, {title: 'title3'},...]
```